# ANTLR simple formula parser

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I have a very basic requirement that build a formula from four variable `r`, `p`, `c`, `s` and three functions `min`, `max`, `avg`.

For e.g.:

```
max(avg(r, p, s), avg(c, s))
```

or it could just be:

```
r
```

I'd like to parse this kind of formulas using ANTLR.

I have tried some grammar `Formula.g4` for it:

```
grammar Formula;

/* Parser rules */

formula : arg EOF;
func: ( MIN | MAX | AVG ) '(' arg (COMMA arg)+ ')';
arg : ( R | P | C | S | func );


/* Lexer rules */

MAX : 'max';
MIN : 'min';
AVG : 'avg';

WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

R : 'r';
P : 'p';
C : 'c';
S : 's';

COMMA : ',';
```

But this doesn't do anything when I run `grun Formula formula` after running `antlr Formula.g4` and compiling the generated Java files.

I am very new to ANTLR. Could anyone please help me find out what I got wrong? Do we define variables the way I did? Also, if anyone has a better solution for this kind of problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you want it to do? Check for syntax errors (it should do that already - maybe you only entered input that was valid or didn't terminate the input properly with Ctrl+D/Ctrl+Z)? Display the tree (use the `-tree` or `-gui` option for that)?

Comment: @sepp2k - Yes, using Ctrl + Z it starts showing me the tree. But How do I set the values for the variables?

Comment: @sepp2k - Actually I'd like to make an `Formula` interface with method `double apply(double r, double p, double c, double s)` and have the parsed formula implement this interface. Is this possible using ANTLR?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the formulae, you'll need to write code to do that. `grun` can't do that for you. Neither does it know that `R`, `P`, `C` and `S` are things that should be assigned values, nor what `MAX`, `MIN` or `AVG` mean (or any other parts of your syntax). It can't infer the semantics of your language from the syntax. You'll need to write Java code that implements the generated listener or visitor interface and then walk the tree using that.

Comment: @sepp2k -  Ok. Also there is something wrong with the grammar. It works for simple `max(r, p)` but not with nested call like: `max(r, avg(p, c))`. It says extraneous parenthesis.

Comment: Works fine when I try it (output: `(formula (arg (func max ( (arg r) , (arg (func avg ( (arg p) , (arg c) ))) ))) <EOF>)`). I don't see anything wrong with the grammar.

Comment: @sepp2k -  Yea. Started working for me too. Not sure what happened. I'll research on the listener and visitor interfaces. Thanks for the help. :)